# Can you use pyfirmata with an Arduino Nano Every?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, arduino-nano, pyfirmata

I have used pyfirmata to program my Arduino Uno, but I only have one of these so I want to try using my Nano Every instead.

Yes, I have tried it. I get this error trying to load StandardFirmata to the board. And yes, I have looked it up, but I can't find any information on it.

```
Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano Every, ATMEGA328"

In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Firmata/Firmata.h:17:0,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Firmata\examples\StandardFirmata\StandardFirmata.ino:28:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Firmata/Boards.h:856:2: error: #error "Please edit Boards.h with a hardware abstraction for this board"

 #error "Please edit Boards.h with a hardware abstraction for this board"

  ^~~~~

exit status 1

Error compiling for board Arduino Nano Every.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "use with"? What do you mean by "I only have one of these" - only one of what? What is the problem you are trying to solve this way, or the specific concern that you have? Also, [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look this up? How did you try, and what information did you find? What do you still need to know? Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Probably yes, have you tried it?

Comment: Support for the Nano Every was added to the Boards.h file about 18 days ago.  Try updating the Firmata library within the Arduino IDE; if it doesn't work now, it's just a matter of time before the new version becomes available.

Comment: @jasonharper I have the latest version of Firmata. Should I be using StandardFirmata or a different version from the Arduino IDE?

Comment: @jasonharper because StandardFirmata still doesn't work. I get the same error message.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what the release schedule is for this library.  Perhaps you could copy the Boards.h file from the repository (https://github.com/firmata/arduino/blob/master/Boards.h) into your installation, rather than waiting;  the 14 lines starting with `#elif defined(AVR_NANO_EVERY)` appear to be the only change that was added to support this board.